# Appending to a dataframe for a 3*8 dataset that runs through a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to log a number of results from a few thousand sporting events into excel via pandas. I've found some very basic walkthroughs online, but don't know how to accomplish exactly what I'm trying to do, as most only loop down 1 row at a time.

| Date | Teams | HT Result | FT Result | Odds | % Win | %Pts | FHG/BTTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/7/2023 | Home | 1 | 2 | 2.5 | 40% | 90% | 70% |
|  | away | 1 | 3 | 3.3 | 22% | 60% | 20% |
|  |  |  |  | 3.4 | 38% | 40% | 30% |

Is what I'm trying to print out. I only need the index one time, and after that just the 3x8 table printed below the previous one, over and over. I figured using a for loop was my best bet?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Brentford", 1, 3, 2.15, 39, 90, 70],["Fordham" , 1, 2, 3.3, 22, 60, 20],["", "", "", 3.4, 38, 40, 30]],index=[Date, '', ''], columns=['Teams', 'HT Result', 'FT Result', 'ML Odds', 'Raw ML', 'Pts', 'FHG / BTTS'])
```

Which creates the table, but I'm not sure how to do the looping? Would I just want to append the outputs every run of the loop to a variable for each column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `pandas.concat`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Brentford", 1, 3, 2.15, 39, 90, 70],["Fordham" , 1, 2, 3.3, 22, 60, 20],["", "", "", 3.4, 38, 40, 30]],index=['Date', '', ''], columns=['Teams', 'HT Result', 'FT Result', 'ML Odds', 'Raw ML', 'Pts', 'FHG / BTTS'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["Another", 1, 3, 2.15, 39, 90, 70],["AndAnother" , 1, 2, 3.3, 22, 60, 20],["", "", "", 3.4, 38, 40, 30]],index=['Date2', '', ''], columns=['Teams', 'HT Result', 'FT Result', 'ML Odds', 'Raw ML', 'Pts', 'FHG / BTTS'])

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

and so on,
`pd.concat` returns you

```
[IN]: pd.concat([df1, df2])

[OUT]:
            Teams HT Result FT Result  ML Odds  Raw ML  Pts  FHG / BTTS
Date    Brentford         1         3     2.15      39   90          70
          Fordham         1         2     3.30      22   60          20
                                          3.40      38   40          30
Date2     Another         1         3     2.15      39   90          70
       AndAnother         1         2     3.30      22   60          20
                                          3.40      38   40          30
```